# How to get Inputs values from textfields and display it as new text

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to get values from user as they type in the Text field and
display it as a new text below.The Problem is I'm not getting the
values from textfield. Here is the code that I have return.

**Code :**

```
Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 150.0, top: 18.0,left: 10.0),
              child:TextField(
                controller: Controller,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  hintText: 'please enter your name',
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 250.0),
            child: RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                setState(() {
                  msg.add(Controller.text);
                  msg.clear();
                });
              },
              child: Text('Add'),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
              child: Container(
                child: Card(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: msg.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index){
                      return ListTile(
                        title: Text(msg[index]),
                      );
                    },),
                ),
              )),
        ],
      ),
```

I want to display the inputs as the user types, the latest values
should display at top of the List.

Comment: why you have - `msg.clear();` ? - comment this line and you will get output.

Comment: Thanks for solution,but I want to display the latest values as first in the card, how can I do that @anmol.majhail

Answer (score 0):

The `TextField()` widget has an `onChanged:` method which is called everytime the input changes.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  String changedText = ""; //you need to set the String here
                           //if you set it after `Widget build()`
                           //it'll be set empty again
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("AppBar"),
      ),
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            child: TextField(
              onChanged: (text) {
                print("changing");
                setState(
                  () {
                    changedText = text; //here you change the text to show it below
                  },
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
          Text(changedText),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: but I want to display the values using a button, not Textfield

Comment: You want to see the text below while the user types **and** display the values using a button? I don't really get what you're trying to achieve ^^"

Answer (score 0):

Use `TextEditingController` object and pass that object to text field.

And use `textEditingControllerObject.text` to fetch the latest value present inside your text field.

Edit:

Create an TextEditingController object.

```
TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();
```

Pass controller object to textField widget.

```
TextField(
  controller: controller,
)
```

Text widget will show your text from textField asynchronously.

```
Text(controller.text)
```

Comment: It's not working can you tell how to apply it.,like can you explain it with using above example.

Comment: @AshishMore i have edited my answer you can have a look at that.

Comment: hi @AshishMore I was looking for a reply to resolve your query.